# Tell packages not to change certain variables

Tags: init-file, package

It seems like some variables that I set at one place in my init file could potentially be modified by other packages that are loaded later.

One place where this has come up for me is the variable `yas-snippet-dirs` which I set after I load `yasnippet`, but which is then modified when I load elpy (elpy appends its own snippet directory to the list).

If I want to ensure that all that is contained in `yas-snippet-dirs` is `"~/.emacs.d/snippets"`, I can simply make sure that I set

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
```

after I load elpy.

However, **I am wondering if there is a general way to tell packages not to modify a variable**. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, or thankfully (depending upon how you see things), the answer is "no".  I would just modify the source of whatever makes the changes that I don't like, but most people prefer to use a major or minor mode hook to set it back to what it was beforehand.

Comment: It appears that elpy provides snippets for python mode, which are stored in a separate elpy snippet directory that gets added to `yas-snippet-dirs`. This seems like an appropriate thing to do, and shouldn't break your snippets for other modes. It also looks like you can disable this feature via the elpy module system. What problem is it causing?

Comment: @Tyler, yes, this is exactly what elpy does AFAIK. It doesn't break my snippets unless I have a snippet with the exact same key. The problem is, that while I find some of the elpy snippets very useful, others I don't like, and since I have it configured so that snippets expand on `SPC` (to fix other issues), I find myself constantly expanding elpy snippets accidentally.

Comment: If you like some of the elpy snippets, then removing the elpy snippets from `yas-snippet-dirs` makes a new problem. It doesn't look like there's a good solution, either you take all the snippets, or you get none. I think this is an issue to take up with the elpy developer.

Comment: @Tyler My solution is just to move the snippets I like to my own snippet directory. This solution works best for me (in part, because I have my snippets under vc and syncing between machines, but I do not track my packages), and I don't have any problem with the way elpy does it (I am sure many users like it the way it is). I was just curious if there was a standard/general way to prevent this kind of thing (i.e., prevent a package changing the value of a variable that I want to set myself) in certain cases. I wasn't trying to ask about yasnippet or elpy, just using it as an example.

Comment: @elethan You can customize the `elpy-modules` variable and remove `elpy-module-yasnippet` from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no "*general way to tell packages not to modify a variable*".

Or put differently: The way to tell packages not to modify a variable is for it to be a **user option**.

And if I understand right, `yas-snippet-dirs` *is* a user option.  If so:

1. Packages should, in general, **not** change its value, once it has been set. 
   The general rule is that user options are for **users** to customize.
2. If they do so then presumably it is because they **must** or they have some other very good reason.

For #1: Contact the package maintainer if you think this is a bug.

For #2: Contact the package maintainer if this is not *documented extremely prominently*. Case #2 should be a rare exception.  It really needs good justification, which should be well documented.