# What happens if variable changed through customize is later changed by package maintainers?

Tags: init-file, customize, variables

For example, lets say a package defines a variable `foo`: `(A B C)`, but through customize, I remove `C` from the list. Now the variable `foo` is `(A B)`. What happens if later, the package maintainers change the variable `foo` so that it is now `(A B C D)`. Will my setting in `customize` continue to be respected? If so, how will I ever no that this list now includes more members?

If that was a little too unclear, here is the actual use case: I have removed `elpy-module-yasnippet` from the list `elpy-modules` as suggested in the comments to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19346/8430). Since the list of modules is now explicitly defined in my customizations file, does this mean that if `elpy` someday adds new and exciting modules, by default I will not have them?

Comment: Yes. It's a feature. Your customized value always takes precedence. Unfortunately, that means that you are not informed of changes in the default. That's particularly problematic if the `:type` of the value changes.

Comment: At least for packages distributed with Emacs itself you can find out which options changed since the last release: `M-x customize-changed`. It shows you all options "*whose meanings have changed in Emacs itself*". If you give it a version argument, it finds all options changed since that Emacs version.

Comment: @Drew thanks for the useful information. I never knew about `cystomize-changed`! At least for my case it seems like the solution suggested in the accepted answer does the trick pretty well without the side effects I was worried about. It is unfortunate that if you customize a variable like `elpy-modules` through the customize interface,  and uncheck an item, it sets the variable to a list containing all checked items instead of removing the unchecked ones, but I am sure there is a reason for this, and I would rather set it in my init anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes, you won't hear about the new and exciting modules. But you can write:

```
(setq foo (remq 'c foo))
```

to remove c from foo. Or clone the repository and use standard version control tools for making any changes to the source you want.